# Copy and paste from host Ubuntu into VirtualBox with macOS does not work

Tags: virtualbox

I have Ubuntu machine running VirtualBox version 5.1.28 r117968 with macOS Sierra 10.12.6 as guest.

I have enabled the Devices → Shared Clipboard → Bidirectional option in the VirtualBox machine but I can't paste anything into the guest nor copy anything from it.

How can I make clipboard to work both ways (or at least from host to guest)?

Comment: Are guest additions even available for macOS guest machine?

Comment: @George There is guest additions cd mounted and I can browse it but it seems I can't install anything from there.

Comment: Yes now that I think it is possible to install guest additions in your macOS, I have used it myself but deleted it. Try remounting it that's the only way you can get what your looking for to work